# Do we need to pay for author registration at a conference to present our paper at an non-archival workshop?

Tags: conference, fees

My paper recently got accepted in a non-archival workshop at a prominent computer science conference. Since it is non-archival, should I still pay author registration (which is between $500 to $1000) to do a virtual oral paper presentation that is less than 15 minutes? That seems like I am paying for the merit to present my work at the workshop instead of my work being worthy enough to be presented...

Comment: Related: [Why do we pay to present at conferences?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/59905/17254) Whether it's worth paying that much, especially for virtual attendance, is a personal decision, of course.

Comment: There’s no way to answer this. It really depends on the conference.

Comment: You can register only for the workshop part of the conference and skip the main conference. This will cost considerably less.

Comment: Do you have the option of paying for the workshop only excluding the (rest of the) conference? For instance, I recently participated in one of ECIS' workshop without registering/participating in the whole [ECIS conference](https://ecis2023.no/) because I won't have the time (and can't be on ground physically to engage my peers). Invariably, we all have different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can answer this question for you. It's like asking "Should I pay $1M for a Matisse?" The answer depends on two factors:

- Do you have the money?
- How much is having a Matisse worth to you?

The same applies to your question: Assuming you have the resources to pay in the first place, how much is presenting at this conference (and participating in it as well -- there are also talks to *listen* to) worth *to you*? We really cannot tell you, it's a question for you to figure out.